# I'm using YUI datatable. How do I tell once everything is loaded?

Tags: javascript, yui

http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/docs/YAHOO.widget.DataTable.html

Is it an event or something?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a link-only question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What are you using as a `DataSource`? If you care about when the `DataSource` is done loading data, you can use its `doBeforeLoadData` event which will allow you access to the `DataSource` before it is consumed by the `DataTable`.

Otherwise, if you are talking about "loaded" meaning that the table has finished being drawn, you can use the `DataTable`'s `postRenderEvent`event.

There are a lot of events for these components that you can listen to.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `DataTable`'s renderEvent as in:

```
myDataTable.subscribe("renderEvent", function (o) {
// do someting with the data
});
```